# golang - how to sort string or []byte?

Tags: string, sorting, go, byte

I am looking for a function, that can sort `string` or `[]byte`:

```
"bcad" to "abcd"
or
[]byte("bcad") to []byte("abcd")
```

The string only contains letters - but sorting should also work for letters and numbers.

I found sort package but not the function I want.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It feels wasteful to create a string for each character just to `Join` them.

Here's one that is a little less wasteful, but with more boiler plate. [playground://XEckr_rpr8](http://play.golang.org/p/XEckr_rpr8)

```
type sortRunes []rune

func (s sortRunes) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s[i] < s[j]
}

func (s sortRunes) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

func (s sortRunes) Len() int {
    return len(s)
}

func SortString(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    sort.Sort(sortRunes(r))
    return string(r)
}

func main() {
    w1 := "bcad"
    w2 := SortString(w1)

    fmt.Println(w1)
    fmt.Println(w2)
}
```

Comment: I changed  `[]rune` to `[]byte` from above code , and it's work perfectly. Can anyone explain me about different `[]rune` and `[]byte` ? Which is better in performance?

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/strings

Answer (score 43):

You can convert the string to a slice of strings, sort it, and then convert it back to a string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

func SortString(w string) string {
    s := strings.Split(w, "")
    sort.Strings(s)
    return strings.Join(s, "")
}

func main() {
    w1 := "bcad"
    w2 := SortString(w1)

    fmt.Println(w1)
    fmt.Println(w2)
}
```

This prints:

```
bcad
abcd
```

Try it: http://play.golang.org/p/_6cTBAAZPb

Answer (score 35):

there is a simple way by leveraging  function `sort.Slice`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    word := "1BCagM9"
    s := []rune(word)
    sort.Slice(s, func(i int, j int) bool { return s[i] < s[j] })
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L9gtTyi5har))

Comment: Sorry, can anyone explain me about different `[]rune` and `[]byte` ? I tried both and returned exactly result. Which is better in perfomance?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur  try these cases: `word := []rune("好你")` and `word := []byte("好你")`

Answer (score 3):

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)
func main() {
    word := "1àha漢字Pépy5"
    charArray := []rune(word)
    sort.Slice(charArray, func(i int, j int) bool {
        return charArray[i] < charArray[j]
    })
    fmt.Println(string(charArray))
}
```

Output:

```
15Pahpyàé字漢
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tiIVle0ZdOV)

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks for your correction. It handles all Unicode characters now.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is, golang does not have a convenient function to sort string.

1. Sort using int

- too much conversion i think
- still using rune to merge as string

```
func sortByInt(s string) string {
    var si = []int{}
    var sr = []rune{}
    for _, r := range s {
        si = append(si, int(r))
    }
    sort.Ints(si)
    for _, r := range si {
        sr = append(sr, rune(r))
    }
    return string(sr)
}
```

2. Implement sort interface for []rune, just remember that

   - `rune` equals to `int32`
   - byte equals to `uint8`

```
func sortBySlice(s string) []rune {
    sr := []rune(s)
    sort.Slice(sr, func(i int, j int) bool {
        return sr[i] < sr[j]
    })
    return sr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can sort a string array in go like this**

// name of the file is main.go

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

/*
*This function is used to sort  a string array
 */
func main() {
    var names = []string{"b", "e", "a", "d", "g", "c", "f"}
    fmt.Println("original string array:   ", names)
    sort.Strings(names)
    fmt.Println("After string sort array ", names)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With generics in Go, there is now [slices.SortFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices#SortFunc) which is able to sort slices without using reflect (which `sort.Slice` uses).

To sort by bytes (but not runes), you can do:

```golang
slices.SortFunc(result, func(a []byte, b []byte) int {
    return bytes.Compare(a, b)
})
```

To sort strings, you can do:

```golang
slices.SortFunc(result, func(a string, b string) int {
    return strings.Compare(a, b)
})
```